# how to use parameterized Query in after sql in datastage?

Tags: datastage

I have to create a table in DB2 and read the query from file in Before/After Sql tab in Datastage.
I am using DB2 connector for this.
I have also parameterized the query but getting below error-
an unexpected token was found '/'.

`create table Temp as(#Query#) with data`

can u help in suggesting how can i achieve this successfully. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try loading the entire query into the parameter, rather than just the table name.